How does Windows' Game controller properties connect to a joystick?
The situation:
We need to use a new game controller (with a joystick only) hardware on Windows IoT. In the properties of "Game Controllers", moving the joystick is visible in the displayed square with the '+'. Our software using DirectX8 API only reads 0 values for x/y axes.
What I've tried so far:

DirectX8 obviously doesn't work, also, it's deprecated
Using Gaming.Input: not an option, we have no UWP
XInput: not an option, we have no XBox (compatible) device
Using joyGetPosEx from MultiMediaSystem: doesn't work

The question:
Obviously Windows somehow can "see" the controller and also recognizes the joystick movements; so what API do they use in this little "Game Controllers" window?
Any other suggestion on how to read joystick data?

Have you looked into the Human Interface Device (HID) category? In the past I've had to query and parse through HID report messages manually to get data from not-fully-supported controllers.

Some devices map other things to axes (potentiometer type trigger buttons for instance) - it's possible that you are reading axes assigned to something other than the joystick. You can try to query the device & check all the various axes or you can try reading a given set of axes & spam the controller.

I believe that "low level programming" (HID and setup API) - instead of using more sophisticated frameworks - will do the trick. Thanks @DMGregory for the shared link.
